# Mocking module call inside object

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have the following code

```
@mock.patch('src.sql_connector.SqlWorkflowConnector')
def mock_workflow_connector(mock_connector):
    mock_connector.return_value.get_connection.return_value = MagicMock()
    mock_connector.return_value.get_cursor.return_value = MagicMock()
    return mock_connector

@mock.patch('src.sql_connector.SqlOverlordConnector')
def mock_overlord_connector(mock_connector):
    mock_connector.return_value.get_connection.return_value = MagicMock()
    mock_connector.return_value.get_cursor.return_value = MagicMock()
    return mock_connector

@mock.patch('src.sql_scrapper.SqlScrapper')
def test_retrieve_metadata(mock_sql_scrapper):
    sql_workflow_connector = mock_workflow_connector()
    sql_overlord_connector = mock_overlord_connector()
    scrapper = SqlScrapper(sql_workflow_connector, sql_overlord_connector)
    data = scrapper.retrieve_metadata("test_sample", "test_id", "test_status")
    print(data)
```

In my test_retrieve_meta_data function I have the following line

```
data = scrapper.retrieve_metadata("test_sample", "test_id", "test_status")
```

This calls a cursor.execute() call

the return value I am getting is

```
<MagicMock name='mock.cursor.execute()' id='4471052104'>
{'sample_name': <MagicMock name='mock.cursor.execute().SampleName' id='4471062824'>}
```

I would like to be able to fix this return value so that I can keep testing with it

How do I go about changing the mock.cursor.execute().SampleName call to return for example "test_sample"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suspect there's an error in your current mocks usage. You are patching `SqlWorkflowConnector` and `SqlOverlordConnector` classes, so `return mock_connector` will return mock for a *class* and  `sql_workflow_connector`/`sql_overlord_connector` are both mocks for classes. Does your `SqlScrapper` really expects classes in constructor? Most probably they should be instances:

```
scrapper = SqlScrapper(sql_workflow_connector(), sql_overlord_connector())
```

To avoid ambiguities, I usually name the mock functions with `_cls`/`_instance` suffixes, so I can always recall what does the returned mock replace. For example,

```
def mock_workflow_connector_cls(mock_connector):
    ...
```

Second, to answer your actual question: just extend the mock object you already have. Example:

```
@mock.patch('spam.SqlWorkflowConnector')
def mock_workflow_connector(mock_connector):
    mock_connector.return_value.get_connection.return_value = MagicMock()
    mocked_cursor = MagicMock()
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.SampleName = 'test_sample'
    mock_connector.return_value.get_cursor.return_value = mocked_cursor
    return mock_connector
```

Comment: Current solution given still returns given
Starting to retrieve meta data from Workflow for Sample test_sample and WorkflowExection test_id
<MagicMock name='mock().cursor.execute()' id='4401068352'>
{'sample_name': <MagicMock name='mock().cursor.execute().SampleName' id='4401069696'>

Answer (score 0):

Based off of hoeflings response I was able to modify and make the correct adjustments. The example provided above does not work as intended.

The solution is as follows

```
@mock.patch('src.sql_connector.SqlWorkflowConnector')
def mock_workflow_connector(mock_connector):
    mock_connector.return_value.get_connection.return_value = MagicMock()
    mocked_cursor = MagicMock()
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.SampleName = 'test_sample_name'
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.ClientSampleId = 'test_client_sample_id'
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.ClientSubjectId = 'test_client_subject_id'
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.ClientName = 'test_client_name'
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.ProjectId = 'test_project_id'
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.ProjectName= 'test_project_name'
    mocked_cursor.execute.return_value.WorkflowExecutionId = 12345
    mock_connector.return_value.get_cursor.return_value = mocked_cursor
    print(mock_connector.return_value.get_cursor.return_value)
    mock_connector.cursor = mocked_cursor
    return mock_connector

@mock.patch('src.sql_connector.SqlOverlordConnector')
def mock_overlord_connector(mock_connector):
    mock_connector.return_value.get_connection.return_value = MagicMock()
    mock_connector.return_value.get_cursor.return_value = MagicMock()
    return mock_connector

def test_retrieve_metadata(t_row):
    sql_workflow_connector = mock_workflow_connector()
    sql_overlord_connector = mock_overlord_connector()
    scrapper = SqlScrapper(sql_workflow_connector, sql_overlord_connector)
    data = scrapper.retrieve_metadata("test_sample", "test_id", "test_status")
    print(data)
    print(t_row)
    assert data == t_row
```

Comment: Ok, so the only crucial difference between both answers is the line `mock_connector.cursor = mocked_cursor`, but the internal representation of the mocked classes wasn't clear from the question, so my guess was that it's just an assignment of `SqlWorkflowConnector.get_cursor()`. The rest is the same.